# CORS issue for Scalable application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-boot, cors, scalability

I have three applications followed by authserver, resource server and front end application in AngularJS. The AngularJS application is running on the Node Server and the other resources are running on Tomcat Server. Through AngularJS using CORS I am able to login to authserver (http://localhost:8081/oauth/token) and I am unable to access resource server (http://localhost:8082/api/devices). The headers are adding like this:

```js
var config = {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'bearer '+authToken,
        'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
    }
};
$http.get(RESOURCE_SERVER + 'api/devices',config).then(function(response){
    console.log(""+response.data);
});'''
```

The headers are not adding to the resource server and getting the exception like CORS issue. My main concern is I am able to login to auth server but not to resource server why it like this?

```
@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    public void destroy() {}
}
```

> **Error :**  : XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.0.130:8080/golive-resource/api-docs. The
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *',
>   but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:9000' is therefore
>   not allowed access.

Comment: Are your servers issuing CORS response headers

Comment: There are two application Auth server and Resource server, I am able to login in auth server, getting CORS issue in Resource Server.

Comment: I am getting the following this error 
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:9000' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: then you should fix the error

Comment: I already added CORS Filter, what else need to do?

Comment: you haven't shown the server code, so all i can do is guess

Comment: I added the filter which is used commonly for both Authentication server and resource server

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that somewhere else in your setup you are also setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header and rather than one overwriting the other they get combined by the server, meaning you end up with two values.

Having two values for this header results in an error. You should therefore find out where else you are setting this header and either remove that instance or remove it from your snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

Actually browser makes preflight request before your actuall request with http request method "options" . so you have to send 200 OK to this request

```
if(httpRequest.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")){
        httpResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_ACCEPTED);
        return;
    }
```

More information you can find at http://enable-cors.org/